# My PC re-start when power comes back after a sudden power faliure

Tags: power-supply

I have run a inverter APC 800va in the main line with a battery exite tubler IT 500. Then a 600 VA UPS before the power to CPU.
Now when the power goes there is no problem at all but when the main supply come back then the problem occurs most of the time my PC re-start.

Please help.

---

Thanks a lot for the answer.

My UPS is Proview 600 VA. And i do not have any software to look how the configuration is.
I have change the Bius setting where it was "Stay off" after Ac Back, I have made the change "Power on". But steel the same result.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a setting in the UI for the UPS.  Did it come with software you can open up and look through?  Perhaps the default is set to reboot upon restoring power.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you have got one UPS plugged into another?  I'm not sure that is a very good idea.  Try using only one of them and see if you still have a problem.
I would try each of them on their own, it is quite possible that you have a fault with the UPS that means it isn't cutting back to mains power fast enough.
I would also try a different PC in case it is the PSU of your PC that is at fault.